# VB Code to Paste as values and Source Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, blueprism

I am using Blueprism to automate a process which uses Excel. I need to copy certain cells and paste as values and source formatting. I am using the following code. After running the job the values were still formulas and not values.

```
Dim wb, excel, range As Object

Try

wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
excel = wb.Application

range = excel.Selection
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=-4163, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=-4122, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False)

Success = True

Catch e As Exception
Success = False
Message = e.Message
Finally
wb = Nothing
range = Nothing
End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to paste values and number formats it should be Paste:=12.

For paste values it's Paste:= -4163.

Paste:=13 is for 'paste all using source theme'.

To paste values and all formatting:

```
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=-4163)
range.PasteSpecial(Paste:=-4122)
```

Comment: Can you give me the code that will replicate the front end button for Paste as Values and Source formatting? Is that not slightly different to paste values and number formats?

Comment: Do you mean you want to paste all formatting? If you do then that's a 2 stage operation - first paste values (Paste:=-4163) then paste formatting (Paste:= -4122) - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks I can't test if until the resource frees up but will accept answer when tested

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't copying and pasting sparklines. Is there something else needed to handle this as well?